# How do I create an Android notification?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I followed their tutorial step by step but I keep getting strange errors.

The notifymanager doesn't have .notify() as a method and any line of code with notifymanager in it must have brackets regardless of where it is within the code.

I'm beginning to think it's a dependency issue, please help!

Comment: What tutorial are you following? I'd like to hope the [official notifications guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activity 1

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;


public class NotificationAlert extends Activity {


private static final int NOTIFY_ME_ID=1337;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.notification_alert);

    /*********** Create notification ***********/

    final NotificationManager mgr=
        (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification note=new Notification(R.drawable.stat_notify_chat,
                                                    "Android Example Status message!",
                                                    System.currentTimeMillis());

    // This pending intent will open after notification click
    PendingIntent i=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                                            new Intent(this, NotifyMessage.class),
                                            0);

    note.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Android Example Notification Title",
                            "This is the android example notification message", i);

    //After uncomment this line you will see number of notification arrived
    //note.number=2;
    mgr.notify(NOTIFY_ME_ID, note);


}
}
```

Activity 2

```
 import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;

public class NotifyMessage extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView txt=new TextView(this);

        txt.setText("Activity after click on notification");
        setContentView(txt);
    }
}
```

Comment: This really would probably be more correct code if it was written 3 years ago, before [NotificationCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.html) became the best and only recommended way of creating notifications as per the [notifications guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)